# Возвращает строку вместо json-объекта

Tags: php, jquery

Есть файл, в котором обрабатываются данные и есть прокси, который написан для для кросс-доменных запросов. Файл, в котором обрабатываются данные, в результате своей работы возвращает json-объект. Однако, если обращаться к этому файлу через прокси-файл, то почему-то возвращается простая строка, которую почему-то невозможно распарсить при помощи `JSON.parse` в jQuery. Прокси:

```
require('../../engine/functions.php');
$origin = getDomain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://search.' . $origin);
$data = $_POST['data'];
//var_dump($data);
if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'           => [
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
            ],
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query(array('data' => $data))
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://' . $origin . '/engine/search.php', false, $context);
    if ($result === false) { 
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
        die();
    }
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    die();
}
```

При попытке парсить такую строку на клиенте, происходит ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0`. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите что за текст Вы пытаетесь распарсить (наверняка пых ошибку кидает) и оттуда копайте.

Comment: На isset надо проверять `$_POST['data']` а не `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON - **это и есть** "простая строка". Чтобы получить из неё "объект", её надо сначала раскодировать.

Также для запроса json можно в php установить заголовок `header('content-type:application/json');`
а в jQuery указать тип данных `$.ajax({url:[url], dataType:'json'})`

Answer (score -1):

Странно, но почему-то PHP по прежнему возвращает строку, а не json-массив(хотя, должен возвращать json). Но это пол беды. Дело было в том, что почему-то первый символ в строке был - пробел. Из-за чего JSON.parse не хотел принимать строку и начинать её конвертирование в json-объект. Проблема решилась удалением пробела.

```
JSON.parse(data.trim())
```